# VBA in Access Looping through multiple excel workbooks Subscript out or Range error

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have been working with this issue for days. I tried multiple different ways. I am attempting to append multiple files into an Access linked table or even a temp table or even into a single excel file. At first EVERY SINGLE TIME on the first attempt the program works perfectly, then after that it stops functioning for a period of time and then starts operating again. When it stop functioning I get an Subscript out of range run-time error 9.I open the proper excel file but for some reason it won't let me set it... How can it OPEN THE FILE but in the next line CAN'T FIND IT??? It is driving me insane, it works, it stops working, then it works again... Any advice or hints would be very much appreciated.

This is just one way I tried to do this but they all end the same.

```
i = 2 'i is created through another loop previously.
j = 0
With MyXL
    .Visible = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

Do
    Set MyXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    MyXL.Workbooks.Open Directory & fileArray(j), Notify:=False, ReadOnly:=False 'Tried True previously but changed since i was making changes to the file.
    Set wb = Workbooks(fileArray(j)) 'DING DING DING!!! WHY??? You WORKED before!!!
    If wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = "System Status" Then
        wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = "PO System Status"
        wb.Save
    End If
    wb.Close True
    Set wb = Nothing
    MyXL.Quit
    Set MyXL = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
    j = j + 1
Loop Until j = i
```

Previously I thought I wasn't closing the workbook correctly, but I have closed the MyXL and previous wb but i still run into the error. I was wondering if this is something that Access/vba just can't do in succession as well. I changed the ReadOnly to true and it still ends up the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Set your workbook to the return value from the `Open` method:

```
Set wb = MyXL.Workbooks.Open(Directory & fileArray(j), Notify:=False, ReadOnly:=False) 
If wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = "System Status" Then
    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = "PO System Status"
    wb.Save
End If
```

You don't need to/shouldn't create a new Excel application instance for every file - set that up before you enter the loop, and close it once you're done updating files.  Check your Task Manager and make sure you don't have a bunch of Excel instances hanging around.